# Sort a dictionary based on 'parent' tuple values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I have a Python 3 dictionary in which the keys are tuples, and values are some strings which correspond to masked regular expressions. I want to remove the overlapping tuples.

**PROBLEM**

Basically, I am trying to build a regular expression which matches a given string. I have a catalog of regular expressions that I iterate through the string, and then the 'matched' regular expressions are stored as a dictionary with their 'span'(tuple) as a key and the regular expression mask which matches that span of the string.

After this, I aim to combine these regular expressions together. However, I am facing one issue which is halting my progress.

**Example**

Consider the log line -

`Mar 29 2004 09:54:18: %PIX-6-302005: Built UDP connection for faddr 198.207.223.240/53337 gaddr 10.0.0.187/53 laddr 192.168.0.2/53`

Once I put this string through my matching logic, here's the dictionary which I generate -

```
pos_dict:

(0, 20) CISCOTIMESTAMP
(23, 35) CISCOTAG
(37, 42) CISCO_ACTION
(68, 83) IPV4
(83, 89) URIPATH
(96, 106) IPV4
(106, 109) URIPATH
(116, 127) IPV4
(127, 130) URIPATH
```

After this, I combine the regular expressions masked by the values (CISCOTAG, IPV4) etc to get a final regular expression here.

However, if I put the same code through this log line -

`2016-11-16 06:43:19.79 kali sshd[37727]: Failed password for root from 127.0.0.1 port 22 ssh2`

The position dictionary generated is -

```
pos_dict:
(0, 4) INT
(0, 22) TIMESTAMP_ISO8601
(4, 7) INT
(7, 10) INT
(11, 13) INT
(14, 16) INT
(17, 19) INT
(20, 22) INT
(32, 39) SYSLOG5424SD
(33, 38) INT
(71, 74) INT
(71, 80) IPV4
(75, 76) INT
(77, 78) INT
(79, 80) INT
(86, 88) INT
(92, 93) INT
```

While this is not exactly 'wrong', we can see that there is no need for

```
(0, 4) INT

(4, 7) INT
(7, 10) INT
(11, 13) INT
(14, 16) INT
(17, 19) INT
(20, 22) INT

(33, 38) INT
(71, 74) INT

(75, 76) INT
(77, 78) INT
(79, 80) INT
```

Since they are already under the span ranges of

```
(0, 22) TIMESTAMP_ISO8601

(32, 39) SYSLOG5424SD

(71, 80) IPV4
```

**ATTEMPT**

Here's the code which I use to match the regular expressions and the generate the complete regex:

```py
def get_order(results: list, string: str) -> dict:
    """
    Get the order of the regex occurence in a dictionary.

    Paramters
    ---------

    results : list
        list matches

    string: str
        input string

    Returns
    -------

    dict
    """

    pos_dict = {}

    for result in results:
        # all_regex is a dictionary of regular expressions matched against their 'masked' names.
        expr = all_regex.get(result)

        # Iterate through the expression and store the span of the matched values as a key in the pos_dict
        for iter in regex.finditer(expr, string):
            pos_dict[iter.span()] = result

    return pos_dict


def get_final_regex(pos_dict: dict) -> str:
    """
    Combine the grok regexes into a final regex pattern.

    Paramters
    ---------

    pos_dict : dict
        list matches

    Returns
    -------

    str
    """

    final_regex = ''
    filler_start = '(.*?'
    filler_end = ')'

    for key in sorted(pos_dict):

        ## DEBUG START

        print(key, pos_dict[key])

        ## DEBUG END

        expr = (pos_dict.get(key))
        q = all_regex.get(expr)
        q = q.replace('/', r'\/')

        if not (('(' in q) and (')' in q)):
            q = '(' + q + ')'

        final_regex = final_regex + filler_start + q + filler_end

    return final_regex
```

**EXPECTATION**

For the log line `2016-11-16 06:43:19.79 kali sshd[37727]: Failed password for root from 127.0.0.1 port 22 ssh2`, the expected value of `pos_dict` should be -

```
(0, 22) TIMESTAMP_ISO8601
(32, 39) SYSLOG5424SD
(71, 80) IPV4
(86, 88) INT
(92, 93) INT
```

so that I can later combine the regular expressions together.

Ideally, this boils down to the problem of 'sorting' and 'ignoring' overlapping tuples.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved in a clearer fashion with a namedtuple representing an index range, a concept of how many items are in an index range, and a definition of what it means for one range to be contained in another range.

```
from collections import namedtuple

IdxRange = namedtuple('IdxRange', 'min max')


def range_size(idx_range): # ex range_size(IndexRange(0, 10)) = 10
    return idx_range.max - idx_range.min


def range_is_contained_in(inner, outer):
    return (outer.min <= inner.min <= inner.max <= outer.max)


def trim_pos_dict(pos_dict):
    idx_ranges = sorted(map(IdxRange._make, pos_dict), key=range_size, reverse=True)
    overlapping_ranges = set()

    for target in idx_ranges:
        overlapping_ranges.update(x for x in idx_ranges
                                  if x != target and range_is_contained_in(x, target))

    trimmed_pos_dict = {k: v for k, v in pos_dict.items() if k not in overlapping_ranges}

    return trimmed_pos_dict
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Not a efficient one, will this do?

```
pos_dict = {}
dupList = []


pos_dict[(0, 4)] = 'INT'
pos_dict[(0, 22)] = 'TIMESTAMP_ISO8601'
pos_dict[(4, 7)] = 'INT'
pos_dict[(7, 10)] = 'INT'
pos_dict[(11, 13)] = 'INT'
pos_dict[(14, 16)] = 'INT'
pos_dict[(17, 19)] = 'INT'
pos_dict[(20, 22)] = 'INT'
pos_dict[(32, 39)] = 'SYSLOG5424SD'
pos_dict[(33, 38)] = 'INT'
pos_dict[(71, 74)] = 'INT'
pos_dict[(71, 80)] = 'INT'
pos_dict[(75, 76)] = 'INT'
pos_dict[(77, 78)] = 'INT'
pos_dict[(79, 80)] = 'INT'
pos_dict[(86, 88)] = 'INT'
pos_dict[(92, 93)] = 'INT'

for key in pos_dict:
    for nk in pos_dict:
        if ((key[0] <= nk[0] or key[1] < nk[1]) and key[0] in range(nk[0], nk[1]) and key[1] in range(nk[0], nk[1])) and ((key[1] - key[0]) < (nk[1] - nk[0])):
            dupList.append(key)


for l in dupList:
    del pos_dict[l]

print(pos_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
{(0, 4): 'INT', (0, 22): 'TIMESTAMP_ISO8601', (4, 7): 'INT', (7, 10): 'INT', (11, 13): 'INT', (14, 16): 'INT', (17, 19): 'INT', (20, 22): 'INT', (32, 39): 'SYSLOG5424SD', (33, 38): 'INT', (71, 74): 'INT', (71, 80): 'INT', (75, 76): 'INT', (77, 78): 'INT', (79, 80): 'INT', (86, 88): 'INT', (92, 93): 'INT'}
{(0, 22): 'TIMESTAMP_ISO8601', (20, 22): 'INT', (32, 39): 'SYSLOG5424SD', (71, 80): 'INT', (79, 80): 'INT', (86, 88): 'INT', (92, 93): 'INT'}
```

Comment: That's actually valid, but if you see the output - (0,22) and (20,22) still exist! Can your code take that into consideration as well?

Comment: Also, the (79,80) could be merged into (71,80)